# mix-blend-mode doesn't work?

Tags: css, html

Inspired from this [example](https://site.uplabs.com/posts/fullscreen-background-video-with-mix-blend-mode-ov), I create [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/7vrdx11r/) which doesn't work. Please check the complete code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/7vrdx11r/).

```
a.videolink:link, { 
font-size: 50px; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
color: white;
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
text-align: right;
width: 350px;
text-decoration: none;
}

<div style="position:fixed;left:150px;bottom:150px;">
<a id="videotittle" class="videolink" href="" target="_blank"> 
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you expect exactly which doesn't work? please explain more

Comment: whats the prob .some of the videos are still playing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FF your problem comes from the `position:fixed` of your element's parent.

I guess fixed elements can't do mix with bottom layers...

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/28/) where the anchor's has been positioned absolutely which will work only in FF.

In chrome, it seems you need to set the element at the same level as the video -> inside the same container...

[fiddle for chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/30/)

Comment: I had to turn off `perspective` and `transform`

Comment: Interestingly, applying `transform` seems to be causing the mix-blend property to not apply. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a surprisingly difficult question to find general solutions to - the answer is usually 'add a background'!

Another issue I just came across is `z-index` resets the stacking content so if you're expecting to blend with the background of an ancestor element this can break that.

For a simple color background you can add `background: inherit` to propagate the background down. Whether this makes sense or not will depend on the structure of your site - for instance it won't work for a gradient if the boxes aren't positioned on top of each other.

Comment: If this is your problem see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873772/using-mix-blend-mode-on-nested-components-with-a-different-z-index