# Using mix-blend-mode on nested components with a different z-index

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I have a setup that uses nested, absolute-positioned divs, and I need `mix-blend-mode` to blend the elements of a div with all of elements that have a lower z-index than that div.

The catch is that **each div must have its own independent z-index** (this cannot be changed for accessibility reasons).

This is easier to explain with an example:

```css
#layer-1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: maroon;
  z-index: 1;
}

#layer-2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#layer-3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

#layer-3 img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layer-1"></div>

<div id="layer-2">

  <div id="layer-3">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

I need the image that's inside of `layer-3` to blend with `layer-1`. If you remove the z-index from `layer-2` in the fiddle, you will see that the blending works properly; however, this is not an option for accessibility reasons, as stated above.

I have made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gabranches/v6cuL2o4/44/

Is there some way around this, or is this just a limitation of `mix-blend-mode`?

Comment: `display:contents;` to  `#layer-2`

Comment: For simple background (color only) you could add `background: inherit` to the layers. This will break for background images because it will 'restart' the background again in the layer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply the `mix-blend-mode` to the div `#layer-2`. This one is on the same stacking context with `#layer-1`. `#layer-3` or `img` cannot blend directly with `#layer-1`

```css
#layer-1 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: maroon;
  z-index: 1;
}

#layer-2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

#layer-3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

#layer-3 img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="layer-1"></div>

<div id="layer-2">

  <div id="layer-3">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

From [the specification:](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#csscompositingrules_CSS)

> Everything in CSS that creates a stacking context must be considered an ‘isolated’ group. HTML elements themselves should not create groups.
>
> An element that has blending applied, must blend with all the underlying content of **the stacking context that element belongs to**.

Related question for more detail about stacking context: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that would also add `mix-blend-mode` to other layers that might be inside of `#layer-2` that should not have the blend mode -sorry I should have included that in my example

Comment: @gabranches in this case it won't be possible if you keep the use of z-index. If a stacking context is created then you cannot have only some elements on that stacking context to blend with outside element. Either all the stacking context can blend or not.

Comment: @gabranches by the way I am pretty sure that we can overcome the z-index and don't use it if you share a complete code where you think it's necessary